# Different row data in Nested Table Row

Tags: antd

I am using Ant Design for my project. I have a scene where i should use Ant Design Nested Table where in every row opens new nested Table to show data. I am not able to show different data for each row. It is showing same data in all Nested rows

This is what i am using

https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-nested-table

Code is as such from Official Doc

Expecting to show different data in different nested row items

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside expandedrow function you can pass a row parameter. Based on the row you can render your own table.

https://codesandbox.io/s/34w7km6o11

In the above sample, you can check how i rendered different data based on that particular row.
I used ternary operator, You can write your own condition

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table } from "antd";

const columns = [
  { title: "Name", dataIndex: "name", key: "name" },
  { title: "Age", dataIndex: "age", key: "age" },
  { title: "Address", dataIndex: "address", key: "address" },
  {
    title: "Action",
    dataIndex: "",
    key: "x",
    render: () => <a href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: 1,
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is John Brown, I am 32 years old, living in New York No. 1 Lake Park."
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is Jim Green, I am 42 years old, living in London No. 1 Lake Park."
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is Joe Black, I am 32 years old, living in Sidney No. 1 Lake Park."
  }
];

const data1 = [
  {
    key: 1,
    name: "I am diff",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is John Brown, I am 32 years old, living in New York No. 1 Lake Park."
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    name: "yes",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is Jim Green, I am 42 years old, living in London No. 1 Lake Park."
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    name: "no",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is Joe Black, I am 32 years old, living in Sidney No. 1 Lake Park."
  }
];

const data2 = [
  {
    key: 1,
    name: "hello",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is John Brown, I am 32 years old, living in New York No. 1 Lake Park."
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    name: "hi",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is Jim Green, I am 42 years old, living in London No. 1 Lake Park."
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    name: "test",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is Joe Black, I am 32 years old, living in Sidney No. 1 Lake Park."
  }
];

const expandedRow = row => {
  console.log(row);
  let inTable = row.key == 1 ? data1 : row.key == 2 ? data2 : data;
  return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={inTable} pagination={false} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table columns={columns} expandedRowRender={expandedRow} dataSource={data} />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a different approach to this problem, I have been looking around in other posts and have not found this solution, I hope it helps:

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Table } from "antd";
import { fakeFirstLevelData } from 
'../fakeDataBase/fakeFirstLevelData'


const firstLevelColumns = [
        {
            title: 'ID',
            dataIndex: 'id_tx',
            key: 'ID_TX'
        },
        {
            title: 'Amount',
            dataIndex: 'amount',
            key: 'amount'
        },
        {
            title: 'Currency',
            dataIndex: 'currency',
            key: 'currency'
        },
]
const secondLevelColumns = [
        {
            title: 'First name from',
            dataIndex: 'firstname_from',
            key: ''
        },
        {
            title: 'first name to',
            dataIndex: 'firstname_to',
            key: ''
        },
        {
            title: 'Date ',
            dataIndex: 'date',
            key: ''
        },
]
const firstExpandedRow = (record, index, indent, expanded) => {
        let data = []
        data.push(record.secondLevel)
        return (
            <Table
                rowKey={record => record.cardholderid}
                columns={secondLevelColumns}
                dataSource={data}
                // expandable={{ expandedRowRender: secondExpandedRow }}
                pagination={false}
            />
        )
    }




 return (
            <div className='container mt-40 mb-40 overflow-x-auto  
tableContainer'>
                <Table
                    dataSource={fakeFirstLevelData}
                    columns={firstLevelColumns}
                    rowKey={record => record.id_tx}
                    loading={fakeFirstLevelData ? false : true}
                    pagination={false}
                    expandable={{
                        expandedRowRender: firstExpandedRow,
                        defaultExpandAllRows: false
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        )
```

This is my fake data , its similar to call a API:

```
export const fakeFirstLevelData = [
    {
        id: '1199343457',
        amount: '127,45',
        currency: 'EUR',            
        secondLevel: {
            firstnameFrom: 'Antonio',
            firstnameTo: 'Juan',
            date: '2024/12/12'
            
        }
    },
    {
        id: '11993453458',
        amount: '1',
        currency: 'EUR',            
        secondLevel: {
            firstnameFrom: 'Carlos',
            firstnameTo: 'Estefanía',
            date: '2024/12/12'
            
        }
    }
]
```

This way I have a json with different levels of information and in each row I can show N fields and by expanding the rows I can show more information of the same row.

Comment: I didn't get this line `rowKey={record => record.id_tx}`

Answer (score 0):

1. make children data with state
2. then pass it to the expan function
3. write the parameter with free text
4. then inside nested table write data[expan.key].children2 inside datasource of nested table.

data[expan.key].children2 is just free text you can change with other. thank you